# How to find touch pressure of android phone screen?

Tags: java, android, touch, android-sensors

I'm trying to find touch pressure for android user.I know about `getPressure()` function provided in android but it only gives value 0 or 1 for some android phones and for some android devices it gives decimal value between 0 and 1.

I'm trying to find pressure values for the remaining devices(which gives value 0 or 1 for touch pressure). 
currently i'm trying to follow this approach:

1) Find the touch pressure by getSize() (this is also giving 0 value for any touch event)

2) After finding area i'm trying to find pressure.

Comment: I have the same problem, on my phone I can only get 0 or 1 (xiaomi mi 6)....but I think that there is no solution beacause is strictly hardware dependent

Comment: Can we use setPressure() to manipulate the Pressure without spesfic hardware ?